# Setting size of Application Icon in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a code wherein i put an image on my Application icon:

```
Title="Test WPF" Height="600" Width="800" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Closing="WindowClosing" Icon="ICON.PNG"
```

I know that the icon size is like 12 x 12 or 24 x 24.

Is it possible to have the Application Icon customize on size? like 40 x 24?

Comment: I can't check, but I assume the default WPF window has a fixed icon size. You'd have to roll your own window control to use a bigger icon.

Comment: That property is for the image that appears at the top-left corner of the window, in the title bar...aka: the System Menu.  You're saying you want that to be bigger?  That would make the title bar huge too.  And I suspect the default is 16x16.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [WindowChrome](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.shell.windowchrome?view=netframework-4.7.2) class to customize the non-client area of a window. In this page there is a section specifically mention the application icon and title.

> The application icon and title are not displayed by the WindowChrome class; they have to be added to the border as custom content.

This is [an example](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wpfsdk/2010/08/25/experiments-with-windowchrome/) on how to do that.